# marshaling structure in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have this piece of code and it generates an error:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct MyItem
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Name;
        public int ID;
        public double ID1;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MyItem[] items = new MyItem[6];
        items[0].Name = "JFK";
        items[0].ID = 35;
        items[1].Name = "LBJ";
        items[1].ID = 36;
        items[2].Name = "Tricky Dicky";
        items[2].ID = 37;
        items[3].Name = "Gerald Ford";
        items[3].ID = 38;
        items[4].Name = "Jimmy Carter";
        items[4].ID = 39;
        items[5].Name = "Ronald Reagan";
        items[5].ID = 40;

        IntPtr itemsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyItem)) * 
           items.Length);
        try
        {
            IntPtr item = new IntPtr(itemsPtr.ToInt32());
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], item, true);
                item = new IntPtr(item.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyItem)));
            }         
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(itemsPtr);
        }
```

When I run this code, I am getting `write protection error in 
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], item, true);`

What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: couldn't you have looked up 38 39 40 etc!

Comment: @David: What do you mean? Can you explain a bit more :)

Comment: are you running on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: I recognise that list of presidents!

Comment: No! VISTA 32bit also tested on Windows 7 32 with the same problem!

Comment: do you get error first time round the loop?

Comment: Sometimes first time, sometimes second times and so on. (Fixed 38,39...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing `false` to the `fDeleteOld` parameter of `StructureToPtr()`.

By passing `true` you are asking the marshaller to delete the contents of `item`.  Since you are filling this out for the first time, this results in a memory access failure because the memory is not yet valid.

The documentation states:

> StructureToPtr copies the contents of
>   structure to the pre-allocated block of
>   memory that the ptr parameter points
>   to. If the fDeleteOld parameter is true,
>   the pre-allocated buffer is deleted with
>   the appropriate deletion method on the embedded pointer, **but the buffer
>   must contain valid data**.

The emphasis is mine.

Incidentally I think the loop code looks neater like this:

```
Int32 addr = itemsPtr.ToInt32();
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(items[i], new IntPtr(addr), false);
    addr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyItem));
}
```

Comment: @user This code originally came from me in one of your earlier questions and the erroneous setting of `fDeleteOld` was actually my mistake. I apologise!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Where can I read more about this flag? Why it would generate memory leak if set to false?

Comment: read about it in the documentation on msdn. There's no leak here because the unmanaged memory does not contain anything to leak.